# 2 decoradores em um método Python

Tags: python-3.x, decorator-pattern, descriptors

Bem, eu tenho uma classe bem simples chamada de Task, onde quero armazenar as minhas tasks para depois salvar em um banco.

No entanto, eu quero ir tratando os tipos dos meus atributos, gostaria que o atributo task_name só aceitasse o tipo string.

Para isso eu tenho um decorador chamado validate_type, no entanto eu não estou entendendo onde está o erro, mas sempre que eu rodo o programa, ele levanta a exceção.

```
def validate_type(typee):
    def _validate(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if all(isinstance(val, typee) for val in args):
                return func(*args)
            else:
                raise TypeError("Voce atribuiu o valor errado")
        return inner
    return _validate


class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, task_name):
        self._task_name = task_name

    @property
    def task_name(self):
        return self._task_name

    @task_name.setter
    @validate_type(str)
    def task_name(self, value):
        self._task_name = value

task = Task('minha task')
task.task_name = 4
print(task.task_name)
```

Esse decorador funciona com funções mas com métodos não.
Acredito que seja devido ao self da classe mas não sei como resolver

Answer (score 1):

Precisamente. Em um método, o `self` vai ser inserido como primeiro argumento na chamada. Na sua verificação você checa o tipo de *todos* os argumentos passados - e o tipo do primeiro sempre vai ser igual o tipo da classe.

Pra deixar claro - o problema não tem nada a ver com "2 decoradores" - o decorador `property.setter` sempre espera uma função que vai receber uma instância da classe no primeiro parâmetro, mas ele não é um decorador "comum" que retorna um wrapper da função decorada. A solução que proponho aqui foge um pouco da sua pergunta, apontando uma alternativa ao `property`, e sem usar decorador algum. O problema específico do seu código é abordado logo abaixo.

Se quiser um decorador genérico para verificar todos os tipos, que você possa usar tanto em funções como métodos, acho que o método mais explícito é aceitar um parâmetro que indique se a função decorada é uma função normal, ou um método, e nesse caso, não verificar o tipo do primeiro argumento:

```py
def validate_type(typee, method=False):
    start_arg = 1 if method else 0
    def _validate(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if all(isinstance(val, typee) for val in args[start_arg:]):
                return func(*args)
            else:
                raise TypeError("Voce atribuiu o valor errado")
        return inner
    return _validate
...

class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, task_name):
        self._task_name = task_name

    @property
    def task_name(self):
        return self._task_name

    @task_name.setter
    @validate_type(str, True)
    def task_name(self, value):
        self._task_name = value
```

(Como sugiro outra abordagem abaixo, não efetuei outras melhorias nesse código. Mas note que se o seu decorador for chamado com argumentos com nome, em vez de posicionais, seu decorador não vai funcionar - eles vem na variável `kwargs`, que esse código nem toca)

Se pretende usar esse decorador em vários setters, aí tem opções mais simples mesmo: ou um decorador simples que verifique direto só o tipo do segundo argumento (o value).

No entanto, **se sua intenção é ter várias properties só pra fazer a checagem de tipo**, aí  a melhor opção mesmo é dar um passo atrás e criar uma classe de Descriptor - isso é, não usar a camada que o `property` fornece que deixa você usar funções como setters e getters, e sim, criar uma classe que já tenha a lógica de setter com verificação de tipo inclusa.

Em outras palavras: criamos uma classe de objetos que deve ser usada como atributos de classe, e verifica automaticamente as instâncias das atribuições em tempo de execução.

Com isso, não é necessário nem usar o nome do atributo com `_` para replicar o atributo na instância - podemos usar diretamente o `__dict__` da instância para guardar o valor de mesmo nome. (Com property também é possível, na verdade).

```py
class TypedAttr:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.type):
            raise TypeError(f"Attribute {self.name!r} must be set to instances of {self.instance!r}")
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

E aí, você pode ter sua classe simplesmente assim - perceba como posso colocar vários atributos com tipo sem precisar de nenhum código de setter e getter para cada atributo:

```py
class Task(object):

    task_name = TypedAttr(str)
    task_points = TypedAttr(int)

    def __init__(self, task_name, points=1):
        self.task_name = task_name
        self.task_points = 1
```

E no terminal interativo:

```
>>> t = Task("teste")
>>> t.task_name
'teste'
>>> t.task_name = 23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in __set__
TypeError: Attribute 'task_name' must be set to instances of <class 'str'>
>>> t.task_points = 25.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in __set__
TypeError: Attribute 'task_points' must be set to instances of <class 'int'>
```

[Veja como funcionam os "descriptors" na documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) - o property, como dito acima, é só uma conveniência para incorporar métodos específicos de get e set mesmo.